# What is the name of the error that doesn't allow you to use :: to resolve an enum?

Tags: c++, xcode4, enums, compiler-errors

When using an enum in C++, I like to use `EnumName::Value` (as opposed to just `Value`).  In C++ this is either a warning or an error, depending on compiler settings.

In XCode, what's the name of the setting that will allow me to *not* have this come up as a compiler error?

[image]

(Taking the `ErrorLevel::` away resolves the error)

Comment: AFAIK in standard C++ it's just an error (unless you are using C++11 "enum classes").

Comment: VC++ flags it as warning [C4482](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173704(v=vs.80).aspx).  This came up because I imported this same code (from another xCode project) and suddenly the error appeared.  There must be some setting that causes it to come up as an error.

Comment: The fact is that it *is* an error as far as the standard is concerned, the fact that VC++ allows it is a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you use [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), your syntax is correct:

  ```
  enum EnumName
  {
  Value 
  }
  ...
  EnumName n = EnumName::Value;
  ```

  Also note, that if you use [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you can *require* usage of `EnumName::Value` instead of just `Value` by using `enum class` instead of `enum`:

  ```
  enum class EnumName
  {
  Value 
  }
  ...
  EnumName n = EnumName::Value; //ok
  EnumName fuuu = Value; // compilation error
  ```
- otherwise, you can wrap your enum declaration with namespace

  ```
  namespace EnumName {
  enum EnumName
  {
  Value 
  }
  }
  ...
  EnumName::EnumName n = EnumName::Value;
  ```

Comment: This is a very nice suggestion. Now it _requires_ `EnumName::EnumValue` format!

Comment: Ah ok.  Also [if you change your _C++ language dialect_ to C++11](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UnduE.png) it fixes the problem :)

Comment: Do you know what this actually says??  ___Microsoft was right___!!